# Problems using Prolog[] with the LevelScheme library

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, levelscheme

I am trying to use `Prolog[]` in `ListLinePlot[]` with the LevelScheme library. Here is a sample of what I am trying to do.

```
Figure[
 {
  Multipanel[
   {2, 1},
   XPlotRanges -> {0, 10},
   YPlotRanges -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
   Margin -> 40,
   XFrameTicks -> LinTicks[0, 10, 1, 1],
   ExtendRange -> 0.03,
   XFrameLabels -> "Time (sec)", BufferB -> 3.5,
   YFrameLabels -> {"Out 1", "Out 2"}, BufferL -> 4.5,
   PanelLetterCorner -> {-1, -1},
   YGapSizes -> {0.1},
   Background -> White
   ],

  SetOptions[DataSymbol, SymbolSize -> 0.1],

  FigurePanel[{1, 1}],
  RawGraphics[
   ListLinePlot[Transpose[{Range[0, 10, 0.1], 
      RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 101]}], PlotRange -> All]],
  FigurePanel[{2, 1}],
  RawGraphics[
   ListLinePlot[Transpose[{Range[0, 10, 0.1], 
      RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 101]}], 
    PlotStyle -> {Black, Thick}, 
    Prolog -> {Opacity[0.1], Red, Rectangle[{0, -1}, {2.5, 1}], Green,
       Rectangle[{2.5, -1}, {7.5, 1}], Red, 
      Rectangle[{7.5, -1}, {10, 1}]}]]
  },
 ImageSize -> {600, 350}
 ]
```

And here is the output if get,

[image]

I can't figure out how to get the shadings I want - shading I have provided in the Prolog.

It would be helpful if someone can tell me what is the problem in the code, and how I can fix it.

Comment: Please try to post a _minimal_ working example! Also ... did you visit http://mathematica.stackexchange.com yet?

Comment: @Verde Can you please tell me what you mean by a minimal working example? The example code that is posted is a sample of what I am trying to do.